# What code runs when I click on an individual tab in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

When I click on a tab in a web page that uses jQuery-UI-tabs, what code is run to actually switch from one tab to another?

Comment: I guess the general answer is, "some code inside jQuery UI". Why do you need to know?

Comment: It sounds like you want to inject some logic - have you looked at the jQuery documentation for tab select?

Comment: No, I'm not looking to inject logic.  I'm having some problems and I would like to step thru the code to figure out how to do what I want.

Comment: The relevant jQuery UI code can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#287

Answer (score 1):

On click on any jQuery UI tabs, `select` event is triggered. If you want you can use this event and write your logic in it.

```
$(".selector").tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { 
       //Write your code here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug to step through each executed function. That may not be necessary as it's just a piece of code that toggles some `display` attributes of elements in a list.

You should [download](http://jqueryui.com/download) the uncompressed version of jQuery UI and analyse the Tabs part yourself.